# 3 DES ZERO_PADDING encryption with crypto-js not replicating PHP outcome (PHP code to Node.js)

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl, lets-encrypt

I'm migrating some **php** code to **Node.js** and I really cant replicate the outcome of this PHP code in Node.js:

- For some context, I want to do a 3DES encryption with zero padding, the openssl algorithm used in the node.js and PHP code is "des-ede3"
- This is the **PHP** code:

```php
    $TokenService = "SECRET_TOKEN";
    $Email = "generic email";
    $Telefono = "generic phone number";
    $PedidoID = "666";
    $Monto = "120";
    $Moneda = "2";
    $P1 = "callback url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    $P2 = "success url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    $P3 = "        [{\"Serial\":1,\"Producto\":\"PRODUCTO1\",\"LinkPago\":0,\"Cantidad\":2,\"Precio\":10,\"Descuento\":    0,\"Total\":20},{\"Serial\":2,\"Producto\":\"PRODUCTO2\",\"LinkPago\":0,\"Cantidad\":5,\"Precio\":20,\"Descuento\":0,\"Total\":100}]";
    $P4 = "11\u0000\u0000\u0000";
    $signature_string = "$TokenService|" . $Email . "|" . $Telefono . "|" . $PedidoID . "|" . $Monto     . "|" . $Moneda . "|" . $P1 . "|" . $P2 . "|" . $P3 . "|" . $P4;


    $signature = encrypt_password($signature_string);

    echo "tcFirma: " . $signature . PHP_EOL;

    function encrypt_password($password)
    {
        // Usa la función hash de PHP con el algoritmo SHA-256
        $password_encriptada = hash('sha256', $password);


        return $password_encrypted;
    }
    // tcParameters
    $tcFirma = $signature;
    $TokenSecret = "ANOTHER_SECRET_TOKEN";

    $datos_de_pago = $tcFirma . "|" . $Email . "|" . $Telefono . "|" . $PedidoID . "|" . $Monto . "|" . $Moneda . "|" . $P1 . "|" . $P2 . "|" . $P3 . "|" . $P4;


    $lnSizeDatosPago = strlen($datos_de_pago);

    $datos_de_pago = str_pad($datos_de_pago, ($lnSizeDatosPago + 8 - ($lnSizeDatosPago % 8)), "\0");

    echo $datos_de_pago;

    $tcParametros = openssl_encrypt(
        $datos_de_pago,
        'DES-EDE3',
        $TokenSecret,
        OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
    );

    $tcParametros = base64_encode($tcParametros);

    echo "tcParameters: " . $tcParametros . PHP_EOL;
```

When running this **PHP** code, it returns a string, and running the code again always returns the same string.

but I have made this code, with **Crypto-js** and I cant replicate the string from the PHP code, furthermore, in Node.js the string that is returned to me, always changes, in contrast to the PHP code, that returns always the same encrypted string.

I have made a Node.js code:

## UPDATE:

After fixing some bugs and improving my Node.js code, now I have:

```js
    const sha256 = require('sha256');
    const crypto = require('crypto');

    // TC firma
    const TokenService =
        'SECRET_TOKEN';
    const Email = "generic email";
    const Telefono = "generic phone number";
    const PedidoID = "666";
    const Monto = "120";
    const Moneda = "2";
    const P1 = "callback url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    const P2 = "success url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    const P3 =    '[{"Serial":1,"Producto":"PRODUCTO1","LinkPago":0,"Cantidad":2,"Precio":10,"Descuento":0,"Total":20},{"Serial":2,"Producto":"PRODUCTO2","LinkPago":0,"Cantidad":5,"Precio":20,"Descuento":0,"Total":100}]';

    const P4 = '11\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000';

    const signature_string =
    TokenService +
    '|' +
    Email +
    '|' +
    Telefono +
    '|' +
    PedidoID +
    '|' +
    Monto +
    '|' +
    Moneda +
    '|' +
    P1 +
    '|' +
    P2 +
    '|' +
    P3 +
    '|' +
    P4;
    const signature = encriptar_password(signature_string);

    console.log('tcFirma: ' + signature + '\n');

    function encriptar_password(password) {
        // Use the SHA-256 algorithm to hash the password
        const password_encriptada = sha256(password);
        return password_encriptada;
    }

    // tcParameters
    const tcFirma = signature;
    const TokenSecret = 'ANOTHER_SECRET_TOKEN';

    let datos_de_pago = `${tcFirma}|${Email}|${Telefono}|${PedidoID}|${Monto}|${Moneda}|${P1}|${P2}|${P3}|${P4}`;

    let lnSizeDatosPago = datos_de_pago.length;

    datos_de_pago = datos_de_pago.padEnd(lnSizeDatosPago + 8 - (lnSizeDatosPago % 8), '\0');

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', TokenSecret, null);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(datos_de_pago, null, 'base64'); // 1st     Base64 encoding
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');

    console.log('tcParametros: ' + btoa(encrypted) + '\n');
```

In a nutshell:

- I can't make the Node.js code return the same string as the PHP code (tcParametros)
- The string generated by my node.js code cant't be decrypted by my (PHP) client API
- The PHP code always generates the same encoded string, but my node.js code generates a different string on every execution.

I do not have much experience with encoding, and cryptography, so perhaps I am doing something wrong?

-please, feel free to ask for any extra information

### update

with the new changes in my Node.js code, now my tcFirma hash ($signature) in Node.js matches the one in my PHP code, also, I am able to generate a string very similar to my tcParametros from the PHP code in the node.js code, but they are not the same and still it can't be decrypted by the PHP client.

- They are really similar (only different by 16 characters), i don't know what I am doing wrong tbh -

Comment: Doesn't answer the problem with the changing ciphertext, but DES and ECB are certainly not correct.

Comment: You should successively compare the intermediate steps in both codes, identify the bugs and fix them one after the other. Already the input `$signature_string` differs (whitespace issues regarding P3 and P4, may be copy/paste issues, output `$signature_string` for comparison), so even with a bugfree code (which yours is not) different outputs would be generated. I would also recommend that you use a simple plaintext for `$signature_string` as long as you fix the code, so that you don't have to deal with formatting bugs of the input in addition to code bugs. This makes troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thanks for the observations! yes, I haven't noticed the issues with the P3 and P4 parameters, now my signatures -tcFirma- (encrypted with SHA256) from Node.js and PHP match, now I'm working in my tcParametros from Node.js to match the output of the PHP code

Comment: Note that the PHP code uses Triple-DES in the 3-key variant in ECB mode, so you must use `crypto.TripleDES.encrypt()` in the CryptoJS code. Thereby, the key must be 24 bytes in size. If it is not, PHP/OpenSSL corrects implicitly, i.e. extends with 0x00 values or truncates. In the CryptoJS code, this key correction (if necessary) must be done *explicitly*.

Comment: Also, to disable key derivation in the CryptoJS code, your key must be converted to a `WordArray`, which CryptoJS supports with appropriate [encoders](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Topaco ! I had to change `crypto-js` to `crypto` because of the deprecation issues,

Comment: Regarding the recently added NodeJS code: The default PKCS#7 padding must be disabled with `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)` (before the `update()/final()` calls). This is needed because `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` in the PHP/OpenSSL code disables padding (`OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` from PHP/OpenSSL is a poorly chosen name, as it does not enable zero padding, but *disables* padding). That's why `crypto.pad.NoPadding` should be used in the CryptoJS code (instead of `crypto.pad.ZeroPadding`).

Comment: Sorry, I meant discontinued [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Comment: @Topaco it worked!! thanks,  yes, the node.js code that I posted was good,  the only problem left was that I wasn't adding the `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)`, thank you so much

Comment: Regarding deprecation: Then you should replace [`sha256`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha256#deprecation-notice) as well. If only because crypto (and CryptoJS) also support SHA-256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else needs it, this would be the **Node.js** code that works as the **PHP** code of my problem:

(3DES encrypt with zero padding using crypto in **Node.js**)

```js
   const crypto = require('crypto');

  // TC firma - initial data
    const TokenService =
        'SECRET_TOKEN';
    const Email = "generic email";
    const Telefono = "generic phone number";
    const PedidoID = "666";
    const Monto = "120";
    const Moneda = "2";
    const P1 = "callback url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    const P2 = "success url (for testing purposes it can be just google.com)";
    const P3 =    '[{"Serial":1,"Producto":"PRODUCTO1","LinkPago":0,"Cantidad":2,"Precio":10,"Descuento":0,"Total":20},{"Serial":2,"Producto":"PRODUCTO2","LinkPago":0,"Cantidad":5,"Precio":20,"Descuento":0,"Total":100}]';
    const P4 = '11\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000';
   //Signature string structure
   const signature_string =
    TokenService +
    '|' +
    Email +
    '|' +
    Telefono +
    '|' +
    PedidoID +
    '|' +
    Monto +
    '|' +
    Moneda +
    '|' +
    P1 +
    '|' +
    P2 +
    '|' +
    P3 +
    '|' +
    P4;

   const signature = encriptar_password(signature_string);

   console.log('tcFirma: ' + signature + '\n');

//HASH with SHA256 algorithm with crypto
   function encriptar_password(password) {
       const password_encriptada =       crypto.createHash("sha256").update(password).digest("hex");
       return password_encriptada;
   }

   // tcParameters
   const tcFirma = signature;
   const TokenSecret = 'ANOTHER_SECRET_TOKEN';

   let datos_de_pago= `${tcFirma}|${Email}|${Telefono}|${PedidoID}|${Monto}|${Moneda}|${P1}|${P2}|${P3}|${P4}`;

   let lnSizeDatosPago = datos_de_pago.length;

   datos_de_pago = datos_de_pago.padEnd(lnSizeDatosPago + 8 - (lnSizeDatosPago % 8), '\0');
   /** as @Topaco said: 
The default PKCS#7 padding must be disabled with cipher.setAutoPadding(false) (before the update()/final() calls). 
This is needed because OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in the PHP/OpenSSL code disables padding (OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING from PHP/OpenSSL is a poorly chosen name, as it does not enable zero padding, but disables padding). 
That's why crypto.pad.NoPadding should be used in the CryptoJS code (instead of crypto.pad.ZeroPadding).
**/

   const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', Buffer.from(TokenSecret), null);
   cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
   let encrypted = cipher.update(datos_de_pago, null, 'base64'); // 1st Base64 encoding
   encrypted += cipher.final('base64');

   console.log('tcParametros: ' + btoa(encrypted) + '\n');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35191215)

Comment: @user16217248 A strange comment, considering this *is* the author of the question.

Comment: @AdrianMole I thought it was NAA, so I picked the 'comment and not an answer' canned comment.